# What units does the rotation argument expect when creating objects?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to create a lamp in blender using python. I want to give the lamp some rotation. As per the [documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.lamp_add) I can set the initial rotation using a tuple of numbers in the function call like this `rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`
this is the specifc documentation for the rotation parameter:

**rotation: (float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf], (optional)) – Rotation, Rotation for the newly added object**

What units is this parameter specified with? It does not seem to be in degrees or radian.

When I try with my example code here where I use `rotation=(0, 1, 0)` to get 1 degree on the y axis. I end up getting `57.296` degrees after running the code.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='AREA', view_align=False, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 1, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

[image]

Comment: related: [Which operations are expecting input in radians and which in degrees?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13865/which-operations-are-expecting-input-in-radians-and-which-in-degrees)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is using radians. `1` radian = `57.2957795` degrees. Without the need to import another module you can use a degree value with `(3.14159 * degrees / 180)` or just quickly import `pi` from `math` if you don't want to define it or you could alternatively use `round(math.radians(degrees))`.

```
import bpy
from math import pi

bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='AREA', ... ,  rotation=(0, (pi * degrees / 180), 0))
```

Comment: indeed it is radians

Comment: I recommend to `from math import radians, degrees` for two handy functions to convert back and forth.

Comment: **Are the rotation angles meant to be _Euler angles_ ?** (I haven't had much luck finding this stated in the documentation and a search on this site led me to this question, so it seems the most appropriate place to ask, rather then generating a new question.)

Comment: @Carel Yep. Blender's rotation system implements a famous paper IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

There is build-in functions for this purpose

```
import math
print math.radians(90)
print math.degrees(1.57)
```

They can be referred from the python mannual 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

line 2 translate 90 degree to corresponding radian. 
line 3 do the opposite thing to translate 1.57 rad to 90 degree.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what those functions do and why they work, please?