# Which operations are expecting input in radians and which in degrees?

Tags: modeling, scripting, drivers

Triggered by [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13852/rotation-in-numbers-is-not-accurate-in-blender-2-71) (unfortunately the OP didn't elaborate on the context), I'm puzzled now: **which operations are done in radians and which in degrees?**
In the 3d window all navigation is in degrees (presuming the Units selected for the scene are indeed degrees), but from what I read, internally Blender is using Radians, leading to some confusion when setting drivers, constraints, modifiers or texture mapping. So far I haven't run into any issues but I'm just trying to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: As far as I know, blender uses radians internally everywhere. Only the UI appears in degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems blender uses radians internally everywhere as of 2.70, except for a few cases listed in the [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.70/More_Features#Angles%3a_Degrees_to_Radians_Internally):

> Blender internally stores angles as radians (even though they are presented through UI as degrees), but in a few places degrees were still being stored, which added internal code clutter, and could generate bugs like [T32843](http://developer.blender.org/T32843).
>
> Here are affected properties:
>
> - **Data**:
>
>   - Lamp.spotsize:
>       Game engine exposed this setting in degrees, to not break the API here I kept it as such (using getter/setter functions), still
>       using radians internally.
>   - Mesh.smoothresh:
>       Didn’t touch to this one, as we will hopefully replace it completely by loop normals currently in dev.
> - **Modifiers**:
>
>   - EdgeSplitModifierData.split_angle, BevelModifierData.bevel_angle:
>       Done.
> - **Postprocessing**:
>
>   - WipeVars.angle (sequencer’s effect), NodeBokehImage.angle, NodeBoxMask.rotation, NodeEllipseMask.rotation:
>       Done.
> - **BGE**:
>
>   - bConstraintActuator:
>       Orientation type done (the minloc[0] & maxloc[0] cases). Did not touch to limit location type, it can also limit rotation, but it
>       exposes through RNA the same limit_min/limit_max, which hence can be
>       either distance or angle values, depending on the mode. Will leave
>       this to BGE team.
>   - bSoundActuator.cone_outer_angle_3d, bSoundActuator.cone_inner_angle_3d:
>       Done (note I kept degrees in BGE itself, as it seems this is the expected value here...).
>   - bRadarSensor.angle:
>       Done.

Answer (score 4):

You can input a value in either radians or degrees by appending a "d" suffix (for a value in degrees) and a "r" suffix (for a value in radians) to the numerical value.

"1.5913513r" => in radians

"1.5913513d" => in degrees

For example, if you click the X-axis rotation button of an object to input a rotation value manually, and write "1r", after you press ENTER to commit the value the button will show 57.3º. Hovering the mouse over the button will show a tooltip saying "radians: 1.000000" (and 57.3 degrees is the approximate value of 1 radian).

You can use this when editing drivers, rotations etc. in case you prefer one unit over the other, and Blender will do the conversion for you.