# Scale of rotation is not matching to the real scale

Tags: objects, edit-mode

At the moment I work on a project with many rotations and many little rotation steps. Now the problem is my rotation scale is not matching to my real object rotation. 360° are not longer 360°. Instead I have to set the rotation at 3.15... for one rotation of 360°. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking could add some more info to your question. Maybe some screenshots of what you mean, or perhaps upload you file

Comment: maybe the rotation unit ? do you see your angle with a 'd' at the end (when editing it) or a 'r' ?

Comment: Did you set the units to radians? Maybe related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13865/which-operations-are-expecting-input-in-radians-and-which-in-degrees

Comment: I see my angle with nothing only the number

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing can happen when you switch the *Units* under *Properties panel > Scene tab > Units dropdown*. You most likely switched *Degrees* to *Radians*.

*Units dropdown:*

[image]

*Degrees selected:*

[image]

*Radians selected:*

[image]