# rotation_euler is displayed correctly in "n" panel but not in python

Tags: python

I am confused, are these not the same, or should be the same?[image]

If they are not the same how would I get the rotation information from the 'n' panel using python? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/what-units-does-the-rotation-argument-expect-when-creating-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same, but in UI the values are displayed in [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)), in Python it gives you [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

$ degrees = radians * 180°/π $

$ radians = degrees * π/180° $

The Blender python API gives you radians because the Python trigonometric functions sin, cos, tan, etc. expect radians as input, so it's more convenient in programming.

For humans it's easier to read angles in degrees, so that's why UI uses it.